# How to set execute-only permission for a php script in a .htaccess file?

Tags: htaccess, php, permissions

I'm really a newbie in web-technologies, so this question may be silly.
I have a php script that accesses a database, therefore it stores a database password (tell me a better way to store this password).
Client-side JS sends Ajax request to this script.

What I want to archive: set permissions for the php script (probably through .htaccess, but i'm not sure) so that it can be called from outside and executed on a server-side, but nobody could access it's content.

Comment: I thought I would help balance out he down votes. Not sure why the down votes. Everyone starts somewhere. Kindness and patience is what us more experienced computer professionals **must** give to those who come behind us. After all, someone did it for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm partly confused by your question, so I'll answer it the best I can.

To set permissions on any file on a server (including php files) there's a couple of ways.

1. If you have a web file manager interface, you can access that and set php file permissions through that.
2. If you have direct FTP access to the server, you can use your FTP program to set php file permissions.
3. If you have direct access to a secure shell (SSH), you can set permissions in that, but that is something I'd only advise advanced users to do.

Regardless of which way you take, the standard permissions are 0x755. This means read, write, and execute permission for the owner of the file, and read and execute permission for the group and others. You'll need to read a linux manual to understand more, but for now, setting permissions to 0x755 is perfect.

If you're asking to protect the internal contents of a PHP file, then they're already protected provided your web server is set up normally. By default, all php files requested by any client are processed with the PHP interpreter then the output provided by that interpreter is then passed on to the client. The client then either sees the output from the php code or an error.

For example, if your php file is this:

```
<?php
    $secret=1;
    echo "Hello";
?>
```

and a client executes the file in a browser, then he/she will see:

```
Hello
```

But if the server isn't configured to have a program handle PHP files, then the client will likely see:

```
<?php
    $secret=1;
    echo "Hello";
?>
```

I hope I answered your question.

Comment: "the standard permissions are 0x755" - Standard perms for a PHP _file_ don't include the "execute" perm (so should be something like 0x644 - it just needs to be "readable"). I think the OP is just using confusing terminology and isn't literally referring to the filesystem permissions. In OP speak: User requests a PHP file and it "executes".

Comment: I see where you're coming from on that. Its because the PHP binary needs to have the executable bit set for the people that need to run it.

Comment: Oh, I see! So, if script runs by default when opened (which is true in my case) there's no way to force server to return raw script? Maybe it's so natural thing that nobody mentions it. Just want to be sure)

Comment: @ViacheslavKroilov Yes, that's correct. However, if "something" breaks with the server or your script or there is a misconfiguration (perhaps as a result of a server update) then code can be exposed. But you still don't want passwords exposed! To prevent this you can store your password file _above the document root_ and only `include` this in your public scripts as required.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding but this sounds like a server-side script?

If this is the case then the script should be run from a designated cgi-bin (script) directory and the server permissions should prohibit anyone from directly accessing this directory (other than to run said scripts). Assuming the script runs correctly and any debugging is turned off, there should be no unwanted output.

Comment: Yup, you've understood right. The problem is that I can't configure the whole server. And I don't know it's default configuration. When I tried to put it in a cgi-bin folder (which I've created by myself) the script became inaccessible even for execution.

Comment: Where in the .htaccess those commands should be placed? If I just raw copy-paste them, it brokes the whole server with a 500 error

Comment: The OP has stated this is a PHP script, not CGI.

Comment: @ViacheslavKroilov Apologies. Yes that breaks the server. PHP is a little different. Those are for normal .cgi implementations. Ignore my bad advice on that point please. =P

Comment: @ViacheslavKroilov That said I would try A) try to find the proper executable directory (if possible) B) make sure any folder has correct permissions to allow access (this might come up in upload scripts where the folder needs to be writable with the proper permissions) and C) that the .php script itself is executable.